# Not Getting response from Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am new to angular js . I am trying to introduce Angular Js into one of my existing application. Below is the HTML and JS

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ldlApp">
<head>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/ldlredesign.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ldlController">
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>
</html>

var app = angular.module('ldlApp', []);
app.controller('ldlController', function($scope) {
console.log(" Inside Controller **** ");
$scope.message = 'Hello from LDL Controller !!!! ';
});
```

In Browser console I am getting the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

The Same HTML and JS is working if I make a brand new sample web application. 
What could be the issue or what I have to revisit in the code to get it fixed?

Comment: What file is this in?  Because you have HTML and (unscripted) javascript all in the same file.  Or if it is not the question doesn't make that apparent.

Comment: JS and HTML are in a different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a temp file issue . I Cleared all temp files from windows , server temp and browser . Now i am getting the message back from controller.